# Dynamic layout within scrollview Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a layout that can have 4 - 10 linear horizontal layouts
Each row having a Spinner and 3 Image Buttons
if i had a structure of the spinner and 3 buttons would be good
the data for the spinner is taken from a Database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearDataFeed"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

```
package com.example.ajd19.dynamiclayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ajd19 on 24-11-2015.
 */
public class DataFeed extends ActionBarActivity {
    int nosubs;
    int day,month,year;

    class rows{
        public Spinner s;
        public ImageButton b1;
        public ImageButton b2;
        public ImageButton b3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_feed);
        try {
            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearDataFeed);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            int n = i.getIntExtra("number", 0);

            rows[] r = new rows[n];
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            SQLiteDatabase DB = openOrCreateDatabase("DB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from Subjects", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int k = 0; k < cursor.getCount(); k++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(k);
                list.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
                l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                r[j].s = new Spinner(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> SpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.data_feed, list);
                r[j].s.setAdapter(SpinnerArrayAdapter);
                l.addView(r[j].s);

                r[j].b1 = new ImageButton(this);
                r[j].b1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_tick);
                r[j].b1.setLayoutParams(params);
                l.addView(r[j].b1);

                r[j].b2 = new ImageButton(this);
                r[j].b2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_circle);
                r[j].b2.setLayoutParams(params);
                l.addView(r[j].b2);

                r[j].b3 = new ImageButton(this);
                r[j].b3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cross);
                r[j].b3.setLayoutParams(params);
                l.addView(r[j].b3);

                linear.addView(l);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ohhh",e.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

[screenshot of the activity obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdfKn.png)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4r9zh27ki4t04nb/AACRpZQuK3Ep0kS1TlxtOgnya?dl=0

And by running this code i am getting a null pointer exception
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.widget.Spinner com.example.ajd19.dynamiclayout.DataFeed$rows.s' on a null object reference`

Have included a screenshot and also the source code please check :)

Comment: Please post the error and line being specified in the stack trace.

Comment: Looks like using list view or recyclerview instead of scrollview fits much better for your problem

Comment: In your xml, you are missing the property `android: id="@+id/R.id.linearDataFeed"` for your LinearLayout.

Comment: comment again if you still couldn't solve it.

Comment: Have added source codes and screenshot please check !!